# Design a JSON interface

Tags: json, web-services, rest, jsonp, json.net

I need to design a JSON interface which when implemented on my end will produce a JSON packet (JSON formatted document) - which could be consumed by remote websites (they will use their webservices to consume it).  Where should I start from.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from a [tutorial](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_json/).
And continue with a more [realistic implementation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/json/getting_started).